# Verify custom table in magento for custom module

Tags: php, magento, module

I have made the redirect  from the question i have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627684/database-getting-updated-wrong-from-custom-module-form-after-validation)
Now i have another form in the redirected page where i need to enter name and mobile number and if it matches in my db table **helloworld** it will go to one page or else to another

```
<p>You have successfully registered</p>
<div>
    <label>Login</label>
</div>
<div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label> Username </label>
        <strong>:</strong>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" type="text" name="fname" maxlength="20">
        <label>Mobile No</label>
        <strong>:</strong>
        <input class="required-entry" type="number" maxlength="10" name="mobileno">
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
    </form>
</div>
```

Can any one help me how no i can verify it with existing data in db and make this work ? Shall I start it with using index controller or is there any magento way?

**Update:**

this is my Indexcontroler.php after below answer update

```
<?php
class MyCustom_Helloworld_IndexController extends  Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

/*
* this method privides default action.
*/
public function indexAction()
{
if($this->getRequest()->getParams()) {
$param = $this->getRequest()->getParams();


echo $firstname = $param['fname'];
$lastname = $param['lname'];
$address = $param['address'];
$state = $param['state'];
$city = $param['city'];
$mobile = $param['mobileno'];



$model = Mage::getModel('helloworld/helloworld');
// $model->setTitle($title);
$model->setFirstname($firstname);
$model->setLastname($lastname);
$model->setAddress($address);
$model->setState($state);
$model->setCity($city); 
$model->setMobileno($mobile); 
$model->save();   
$this->_redirect('helloworld/index/login');
// $this->_redirectReferer();
}else {


/*
* Initialization of Mage_Core_Model_Layout model
*/
$this->loadLayout();
/*
* Building page according to layout confuration
*/
$this->renderLayout();

}



}
public function loginAction()
{
$this->loadLayout();     
$this->renderLayout();

}
public function loginnAction()
  {
  if($this->getRequest()->getParams()) {
  $param = $this->getRequest()->getParams();


      $username = $param['fname'];
      $mobile = $param['mobileno'];

      $check = Mage::getModel('helloworld/helloworld')
                ->AddFieldToFilter('mobileno', array('eq' => $mobile))
                ->AddFieldToFilter('fname', array('eq' => $username));
 if(count($check)==1) {
 $this->_redirectReferer();
 }else {
 $this->_redirect('helloworld/index/login');
  }

}
}
}
```

Comment: where is username field that are not part of previous question?

Comment: thats fname which i have labeled to username here

Comment: add the answer try and feedback...

Comment: i have a public function loginAction() already define in my index controller

Comment: change it where you want to submit this form it is a example action..

Comment: that loads the page and shows the same login redirected page

Comment: what you want to achieve if the result is correct? and what will happen if result is incorrect?

Comment: as for now if it is correct just redirect to home page and if wrong load the login page again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95339/discussion-between-melvin-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 0):

you can add check like that

```
    public function loginAction()
          {
          if($this->getRequest()->getParams()) {
          $param = $this->getRequest()->getParams();


              $username = $param['fname'];
              $mobile = $param['mobile'];

              $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');

$table = $connectionresource->getTableName('helloworld/helloworld');
$allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('helloworld'=>$table))->where('helloworld.mobileno=?', $mobileno)
->where('helloworld.fname=?', $username);
$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
    if(count($alldata)==1) {
       $this->_redirect('home');
         }else {
        $this->_redirect('customer/account');
          }

      }
```

Comment: i have renamed public function loginAction() to public function loginnAction() , will that be a problem ? it still loads the same page

Comment: not that will be not problem and it will not load same page. what is your form action?

Comment: i havent given any action